# Angular 4 ng build prod style SyntaxError

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-cli, dev-to-production

**Angule 4.3.3, angular cli, MVC**

When i compile my code in my dev enviroment with ng build all works fine i can see the styling.

but when i do ng build -prod for prodaction enviroment the complitaion success i do get all js bundle files.

but in the browser (Chrome) i get an error:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token**

on file **styles.14098r3...bundle.css**

in my tsconfig.json, the target: "es5".

why in my dev enviroment all works fine but in my prod the style not working?

please help me to resolve this problem.

## Edit:

I in dev the html tag for style look like:

```
<script src="/dist/styles.bundle.js"></script>
```

but in prod html for style look like:

```
<script src="/dist/styles.149025e8452.bundle.css">
```

if i change the prod style tag to link instead script the style work fine.

---I generate the script from mvc bundles---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same issue. Here's what I ended up doing:

In your bundle config:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular-components")
                .Include("~/Client/app/dist/inline.bundle.js")
                .Include("~/Client/app/dist/polyfills.bundle.js")
                .Include("~/Client/app/dist/styles.bundle.js")
                .Include("~/Client/app/dist/vendor.bundle.js")
                .Include("~/Client/app/dist/main.bundle.js")
                .IncludeDirectory("~/Client/app/dist/", "*.js.map", false));


bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/angular-components-style").Include(
                "~/Client/app/dist/styles.bundle.css")
            );
```

In your layout, you import both the style and script bundle:

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/angular-components-style")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular-components")
```

And when you build your angular app, use the no hash option:

```
ng build --prod --watch -oh none
```

That way if you build for with or without the `--prod` option, your output files will not have any hash. When in dev, it will render the `styles.bundle.js` as a script and when built in prod, it will render it as a link using `styles.bundle.css`